# Magento 2 assign isSelected on new address book checkout page

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

i need help on overriding shipping.js from core magento

i've create new mixing extend from `Magento_Checkout/view/shipping.js`

```
    var mixin ={
​
        saveNewAddress: function () {
            var addressData,
                newShippingAddress;
​
            console.log('save new address overriden');
            this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
            this.triggerShippingDataValidateEvent();
​
            if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
                addressData = this.source.get('shippingAddress');
                // if user clicked the checkbox, its value is true or false. Need to convert.
                addressData['save_in_address_book'] = this.saveInAddressBook ? 1 : 0;
​
                // New address must be selected as a shipping address
                newShippingAddress = createShippingAddress(addressData);
                selectShippingAddress(newShippingAddress);
                checkoutData.setSelectedShippingAddress(newShippingAddress.getKey());
                checkoutData.setNewCustomerShippingAddress($.extend(true, {}, addressData));
                this.getPopUp().closeModal();
                this.isNewAddressAdded(true);
            }
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    }
```

how can i select this new address book after save new address book added on checkout page before checkout process so i can process on my custom 
`shipping-address/address-renderer/default.js` ?

Comment: you want to show new address in checkout page as shipping and billing am I right?

Comment: yes as shipping and billing address and that address ```isSelected(true)```

Comment: I think you can direct pass like this                 checkoutData.setNewCustomerShippingAddress(addressData); and this line this.shippingAddressComponent().isNewAddressAdded(true);